# How to use Yelp's new API

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, yelp

I am pretty new to programing so I am sure this is not correct but its the best I can do based on my research. Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import yelp
requests.get(https://api.yelp.com/v3/autocomplete?text=del&latitude=37.786882&longitude=-122.399972,headers={'Authorization: Bearer <API KEY that I have>'})
```

My noob self tells me this is a dictonary

```
headers={'Authorization: Bearer <API KeY>'}
```

I know this is prob 100% wrong so I would really love to learn more about using rest API's in Python. I am just doing this as a personal project. My overall goal is to be able to access yelps public data via API. For example, I want to get the reviews for business X.

Update

```
requests.get("https://api.yelp.com/v3/autocomplete?text=del&latitude=37.786882&longitude=-122.399972",headers={'Authorization: Bearer <API KEY>'})
```

I now get the following error

```
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: Hey @g_altobelli, this looks roughly right but it's hard to say exactly without a little more information about what you're trying to do! Can you add some specifics about your goal in your original post?

Comment: @PeterDolan thanks for the feedback, I made sure to update my overall goal.

Comment: nice! This looks good. I'll do some research and give you an answer in the next 15 minutes

Comment: What you have is a `set`. A dictionary would look like `{'Authorization': 'Bearer <API KEY>'}`. You should also quote the URL in that `requests.get()` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're definitely not 100% wrong @g_altobelli!

Let's take the example of getting reviews for business X, where X is one of my favorite restaurants -- la taqueria in San Francisco. Their restaurant id (which can be found in the url of their review page as the last element) is `la-taqueria-san-francisco-2`.

Now to our code:

You have the right idea using requests,  I think your parameters might just be slightly off. It's helpful inititally to have some headers. Here's what I added:

```
import requests

API_KEY = "<my api key>"

API_HOST = 'https://api.yelp.com'
BUSINESS_PATH = '/v3/businesses/'
```

Then I created a function, that took in the business id and returned a jsonified result of the basic data. That looked like this:

```
def get_business(business_id):
    business_path = BUSINESS_PATH + business_id
    url = API_HOST + business_path + '/reviews'
    headers = {'Authorization': f"Bearer {API_KEY}"}

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    return response.json()
```

Finally, I called the function with my values and printed the result:

```
results = get_business('la-taqueria-san-francisco-2')
print(results)
```

The output I got was json, and looked roughly like the following:

`{'reviews': [{'id': 'pD3Yvc4QdUCBISy077smYw', 'url': 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/la-taqueria-san-francisco-2?hrid=pD3Yvc4QdUCBISy077smYw&adjust_creative=hEbqN49-q6Ct_cMosX68Zg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_reviews&utm_source=hEbqN49-q6Ct_cMosX68Zg', 'text': 'My second time here.. \nI love the Burito here it has the distinct taste of freshness.. we order super steak burito and boy it did not disappoint! everything...}`

Does this help? Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Oh my! Thank you so much for this, I honestly cant thank you enough for all your help. I am a Math/Econ major so I really want to observe the influence of social media on local small businesses.

Comment: No problem :) hopefully you can get some cool results! Ping me if you have any further questions!

Comment: Honestly, the headers you made followed by a function cleared everything up so well. I can learn so much just from that part. I can tell you are an amazing software engineer. Thank you!