# Trying to use Yelp API for something other than business_id

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a student and only a few weeks into Python, so bear with me. I found a good answer in this link for initially working with Yelp's v3 API to at least get it to successfully make a request by business_id: [How to use Yelp's new API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49502551/how-to-use-yelps-new-api)

However, I can't seem to figure out how to search by anything other than reviews using the code that someone provided above (copy-pasted here as the below does work, just not what I need it for:

```
import requests
import yelp
from config import api_key

API_KEY = api_key
API_HOST = 'https://api.yelp.com'
BUSINESS_PATH = '/v3/businesses/'

def get_business(business_id):
    business_path = BUSINESS_PATH + business_id
    url = API_HOST + business_path + '/reviews'
    headers = {'Authorization': f"Bearer {API_KEY}"}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

return response.json()

results = get_business('the-white-horse-pub-kansas-city')
pprint(results)
```

Again, the code does work if you're only looking up one place by name. But when I try something other than "/reviews" in the url function, such as "search" or "term" or something else going off of the Yelp Fusion API documentation (https://yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business_search), I can't get anything to pull. My intent is to pull a bunch of breweries in the local area and then eventually put them in a dataframe, but I can't figure out what parameters or code to use, other than 'review'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found an answer where you can at least look for type if you add the first item to the dependencies and the lower items as a separate function:

```
BUSINESS_PATH_CAT = '/v3/categories/'

def get_all_categories(alias):
url = API_HOST + BUSINESS_PATH_CAT + alias
headers = {'Authorization': f"Bearer {API_KEY}"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
return response.json()

results = get_all_categories('brewpubs')
pprint(results)
```

Aside from this though, on the authentication guide for Yelp Fusion, it discusses using Postman. If you're a fellow noob, setting this up can be a lifesaver as this allowed me to actually see the HTTP wording and how it's split up for search terms and how to add them compared to the API documentation.